# R file is not generating the necessary variables

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to produce my first Android app, HelloWorld. I'm following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html), but it doesn't comment on my problem. I can't run the app because of an error in MainActivity.java, on "container" at the commented line:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()) //error line
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    //more code
```

The suggested solutions from Eclipse are adding field or constant "container" to type "id". When I try to do this, Eclipse automatically reverts the change.

The file is autogenerated and I have no clue what goes on in it because I'm a complete beginner with Android development. How do I solve or get around this error?

The mouseover text of the error says "container cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure you have a component with an id value of `"container"` in your XML views.

Comment: where should it go though? The code implies it should be in "id" but changes I make there are auto-reverted by Eclipse

Comment: Review your XML views or follow the tutorial in the right way. I checked the link you posted and there's no Java code in it. Looks like you're mixing tutorials.

Comment: I followed the tutorial I posted. The link doesn't give the start of the tutorial. The tutorial instructs me how to start a new project, and I followed it carefully. Starting a new project generates a bunch of files, including this one. The MainActivity.java file is not mentioned so far, but I had to access it to investigate the error keeping me from running the app.

Comment: Well, comment everything below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have any widget with id = container in your activity_main.xml. If you want, you can set the id of the LinearLayout to container as follows (by adding another line):

```
android:id="@+id/container
```

In this case, the fragment will get added to the LinearLayout below the EditText and Button widgets.

Comment: In your case, you can use the root LinearLayout itself as the container.

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.container` should be an ID in the layout `R.layout.activity_main`

You have to edit the `layout/activity_main.xml` to have that

**edit:**

the line

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()) //error line
                .commit();
```

is adding the fragment to a `ViewGroup` with id `R.id.container`. The `PlaceholderFragment` will create its View inside that `ViewGroup`.

I know it all sounds a bit confusing now that you're starting, but soon it will all be natural.

Comment: i updated Q with my activity_main.xml. What should R.id.container be child of?